# scroll bar in pageblocktable in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I am using a "pageblocktable" to display a list of data in my application. My problem here is that the list contains more than hundred rows of data. My question is, is it possible to add a scroll bar to the table and set the number of rows that are visible or set the height to the table?

Or If a scroll bar is is not possible can pagination be added to the visualforce page is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Pagination is definitely possible. You can use the standard set controller or the newer OFFSET feature in SOQL to do this.

Check this out. 
http://www.redpointsolutions.com/add-pagination-to-your-visualforce-pages-using-the-soql-offset-clause